# Lightning Tensorboard not working in Kaggle

Tags: tensorboard, kaggle, pytorch-lightning

```
%reload_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir=lightning_logs/
```

The cell is running but the board is not created, in kaggle.

Comment: Facing the exact same issue.